# «Вот те крест» — вводное выражение или нет?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, междометие

**Вот те крест** — является ли вводным и нужно ли его выделять запятыми?
(В значении "я клянусь", "честно", "ей-богу".)

*Я больше не буду(,) вот те крест(,) не буду.

Дима, я не брал твои книги(,) вот те крест.*

Comment: Это экспрессивная речь, так её могут называть - https://old.bigenc.ru/linguistics/text/4927818 , надо отделять запятой, как вводные, риторические вопросы и тп.

Comment: Так что же это такое, три варианта, кто правее? Неужели современных источников нет?  https://kartaslov.ru/значение-слова/вот+те+крест  https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/27391/Вот  https://slovar.cc/rus/lopatin/963506.html

Comment: https://gufo.me/dict/mikhelson/вот_тебе_крест  В общем история умалчивает. Неизвестно, что это такое, но запятыми выделяют все.ВОТ ТЕ КРЕСТ
Русский орфографический словарь
вот те крест и вот тебе крест (клятвенное уверение)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Вот те крест](https://orthography.academic.ru/4333/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82_%D1%82%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82) — междометие, просторечное (Б. З. Букчина. Слитно. Раздельно. Через дефис).

**Истинный** (или **святой**) **крест!** и **вот те крест!** ( *прост. устар.*) — слова клятвы, обычно сопровождаемые крестным знамением. — *Это правда? — Вот те крест, правда! — побожилась Дашутка.* Седых, Даурия (Словарь русского языка под ред. А. П. Евгеньевой).

> Междометия — это слова, которые выражают наши чувства, переживания и побуждения к действию, не называя их. Они не изменяются, т. е. не имеют категории рода, числа, падежа, лица, времени и т. д.

По своей характеристике (*ей-богу, честное слово, клянусь богом, видит бог*) оно очень близко в вводным сочетаниям и в предложении обособляется (чаще всего запятыми).

• *Я больше не буду, **вот те крест,** не буду.

Дима, я не брал твои книги, **вот те крест.***

• Примеры из Нацкорпуса:
*Не отстанет твой кобелина, до конца забьем, **вот те крест свят!*** (П. Л. Проскурин. Судьба);
*— Хотя, **вот те крест,** ваше благородие, деревцо позарез нужно* (Ю. М. Нагибин. От письма до письма);
*Царская собака, **вот те крест святой!*** (Юрий Казаков. Арктур ― гончий пес);
*— Доведись мне, я бы с такими деньгами какое-никакое, но собственное дело открыл бы. **Вот те крест —** открыл бы!* (Сергей Залыгин. Бабе Ане ― сто лет).

Answer (score 3):

Вводное.

> вот те крест, убей меня бог, клянусь, ей-богу, истинный бог, как бог
> свят, клянусь богом, побей меня бог, бог свидетель, убей меня гром,
> истинный крест, истинный гром, побей меня гром, видит бог

*Я больше не буду, вот те крест, не буду.*

*Дима, я не брал твои книги, вот те крест.*

Answer (score 2):

Дополнительная информация

§ 1702. <...> К числу **междометий** со специализированными семантическими функциями относятся:

*ай-ай-ай, ба, боже сохрани, бог с тобой, браво, бррр, вона* (прост.)*, **вот те крест**, вот те христос, вот тебе на, вот тебе раз, вот так так, гм, господь с тобой, да ну, дьявол, ей, ей-богу, ей-же-ей, ей право* (устар.), *еще чего, и-и-и (и-и полно), как бы не так, как же, на-поди, на тебе (нате), ну да (ну да, как же), ну и ну, ну уж, однако, ой-ли, ох, поди ж ты, подумаешь, помилуйте, скажите (скажите на милость), слава богу, то-то (вот то-то, то-то и оно-то), тю, тьфу, увы, ф-фе, фи, фрр, фу, ха, х-хе, хи, хо, ужо* (прост.), *упаси бог, ура, черт, черт-те что, что за черт, черта с два, чтоб тебя, сейчас* (в произношении — *щас*), *эва, эк, эка, эх, эхма.*

§ 1705. <...> В одних случаях междометие употребляется как вводное слово...

• В нашем случае **междометие** использовано в качестве вводного сочетания.

[Русская грамматика](https://emirsaba.org/russkaya-grammatika-sostoit-iz-dvuh-tomov-t.html?page=148) (междометия)

Comment: с стороны да, но с другой, это же открывает ящик пандоры, сейчас повалят вопросы: нужно ли обособлять "вот те хвост", "вот тебе лапка", "вот тобе ус-таки"...